# Get article id from created article in chronoforms

Tags: dynamic, article, chronoforms

I've got a small problem with Chronoforms and the Submit Article action which Chronoforms has. I need to get the article ID of the created article from the Chronoforms array, but it seems that $form->data["article_id"] doesn't give something back. Funny thing is though, when I look at the debugger, there is indeed an article_id field which contains the ID of the created article...

My form works the following: it has a couple of fields which the user fills in. Then I use these fields to fill in an static article with dynamic fields, and at the end of the article I link to this article to get a popup with a Read More reference.

I really don't understand what is going wrong. I need to get all the values out of the form first before I can make the article, but I can only get the article ID if the article is actually already made, this seems contradictory... :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the form to create a new article then the article id is only available after the Joomla! Article action has executed. You can use the id in any following actions.